# Not able to insert multilevel association JPA repository spring boot

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
var component = new RFI();
        component.setProject(project);
        component.setStatus(RFI_STATUS_NOT_STARTED);
        component.setRfiType(entityManager.getReference(RFIType.class,payload.componentTypeId()));
        /* Product Demo */
        if(payload.componentTypeId() == RFI_TYPE_PRODUCT_DEMO){
           var section = new RFISection();
           section.setRfi(component);
           component.setSections(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(section)));
           var question = RFIUtil.createDefaultQuestion(section,questionTypeRepository.findByQuestionTypeIgnoreCase(TYPE_TEXT)
                   .orElseThrow(()->createException(NOT_FOUND,ERROR_QUESTION_NOT_FOUND)));
           question.setValidation(objectMapper.createObjectNode().put("noOfFiles",PRODUCT_DEMO_DEFAULT_FILE_COUNT));
           question.setSection(section);
           section.setQuestions(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(question)));
        }
        var createdComponent = rfiRepository.save(component);
```

I have three Entity RFI,Section,Question.
One RFI Can have many section
and once section can have multiple questions.
These entity are associated bidirectionally.
But when I try to save RFI it is only saving RFI and Section but not the questions.
Please let me know what I am missing? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing Cascade type on questions. After adding CascadeType.ALL it is working fine.